# onItemLongClick won't update a view item in listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, onlongclicklistener

Good day!

I would like to know the reason on why onItemLongClick won't update a view item in listview but when i used onItemClick it work as expected this is the snippet of my code. My apologies i forgot to add return statement in that snippet but the problem still unresolved.

```
private void updateView(int position) {
    View v = listView.getChildAt(position -
            listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

    ImageView tempImgView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatarIcon);
    if (listView.isItemChecked(position)) {
        tempImgView .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_24dp);
    } else {
        tempImgView .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_uncheck_24dp);
    }
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
        long id) {
        updateView(position);
        return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    updateView(position);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: post updateView().

Comment: your code won't compile even.

Comment: Hi All my apologies i forgot to add return statement but the issue is still unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return true, so android will know that your click has been consumed.

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    updateView(position);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Correct, I would only add, that with returning true, Android won‘t be bothered with onItemClick events in case he implements it somewhere in code too.

Comment: Hello there my apologies forgot to add return statement on that issue but the still issue is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to return true value of onItemLongClick listener, try this :-

```
    @Override
     public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int   position,
        long id) {
     updateView(position);
    return true;
     }
```

Hope this will help you . :)

Comment: Hi there thanks for your feedback but my apologies i forgot to add return statement but the issue is still unresolved.

Answer (score -1):

After instantiate your item view, set:

```
yourItemView.setLongClickable(true);
yourItemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

And remember to add the long-click event return:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    updateView(position);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: OnItemLongClick is a callback for itens inside a listView, onLongClickListener will add a lot of callbacks for each item.

Comment: Hi There thanks for your feedback. I have already instantiate all the views and listener also my apologies i forgot to add my return statement in there but still the issue is unresolved